# cannot perform raw query with DB::select(DB::raw()) after updating to laravel 10

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-10, raw-query-builder

after updating to laravel 10, i cant perform raw query like this:

```
$statement = 'SELECT';
    foreach ($tables = collect(availableTables()) as $name => $table_name) {
        if ($tables->last() == $table_name) {
            $statement .= "( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table_name) as {$table_name}";
        }
        else {
            $statement .= "( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table_name) as {$table_name}, ";
        }
    }
    $query  = DB::select(DB::raw($statement));
```

this returns me the following error:

```
PDO::prepare (): Argument #1 ($query) must be of type string, Illuminate\Database|Query\ Expression given
```

what should i do to fix this issue

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't need to use `DB::raw()` inside `DB::select()`:

```php
DB::select("select @@sql_mode");
```

So, you can just use the following instead:

```php
$query = DB::select($statement);
```

Comment: Thanks @Ron Marsden, is this change available somewhere on the Laravel docs?

Comment: @Leutecia it's not a change - this has been the way in Laravel since at least 6.x, perhaps earlier. See "[Running A Select Query](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/database#running-a-select-query)" on the documentation.

Comment: then how come it doesn't show any error on laravel 8?

Comment: @Leutecia There's no error in previous Laravel versions, because DB::raw was only recently modified, as it's documented [in the upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/upgrade#database-expressions).

Answer (score 4):

you need to convert into the string before laravel 10 automatically converted into string now we need to do manually

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

DB::raw($query)->getValue(DB::getQueryGrammar());
```

or create a one helper method

```
if (! function_exists('rawQuery')) {
    function rawQuery($query): string
    {
        return DB::raw($query)->getValue(DB::getQueryGrammar());
    }
}
```

or create a new facade and extend DB facade here

```
<?php

namespace App\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class DBO extends DB
{
    public static function raw($query){
        return parent::raw($query)->getValue(parent::getQueryGrammar());
    }
}
```

**Then add into app/app.php for overwrite db facade**

```
'aliases' => Facade::defaultAliases()->merge([
    'DB' => App\Facades\DBO::class,
])->toArray(),
```

**i m using last way because not need to change any code in the project**

Answer (score 1):

For Laravel 10 This fixed my problem:

```
DB::select(DB::raw('select 1')->
getValue(DB::connection()->getQueryGrammar()));
```